# How do I control how bold an HTML element is with external CSS

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I am trying to customise the font-weight of some HTML on my website using the following CSS.

```
p{
font-weight: 1.2px;
}
```

It is not allowing me to adjust the font weight by adjusting the font-weight value. How can I make the text bolder or lighter with external CSS like above?

Comment: See this page for valid values for `font-weight`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

Comment: you are giving Incorrect value. 
Check here: http://htmldog.com/references/css/properties/font-weight/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use **`px`** in font weight it's not **supported format** for that, try this, it will work for you-

```
p{
  font-weight: 100;
}
p{
  font-weight: 900;
 }
```

or you can use

```
p{
  font-weight: normal;
}
p{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[**Referral link**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Px isn't a valid measurement of font weight. Try a weight like "normal", "bold", or "bolder", or increments of 100 from 100 - 900.

Example:

```
p { font-weight: 700 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The font-weight property sets how thick or thin characters in text should be displayed.

You can go from 100 to 900 where 400 is the same as normal, and 700 is the same as bold.

Dont use "px"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
p.custom-weight
{
        font-weight: 700;
}
```

you do not need 'px' and you can use a class for more power over the p

Answer (score 0):

Enter the decimal value then its works,400 is the same as normal, and 700 is the same as bold.

```
p{
  font-weight: 400 !important;
 }
```